# Running multiple instances of an Applet on a server

Tags: java, client-server

I have a working game created as an applet. I am currently adding multiplayer capability to it in a client/server architecture.

When x number of people has connected to the server, i want to start an instance of the game applet on the server, which is tied to these players. So each time i get a packet from one of these players, i can now e.g. move the player in this instance of the game.

However, an applet doesn't have a constructor per say, it is the init() method as far as i understand which is called by the browser.. So as i am not opening an applet through the browser, but trying to make an instance of it, from the server, how can i actually make this happen?

Hope you understand my question, looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Applets don't run on the server, they run on the client.

Comment: Right.. that makes sense. Can i simulate the same behavior of the applet on the server using something else than an applet?

Comment: Even if you could, you'd be doing the wrong thing. Applets are just the front ends that show what the server tells them to show. The server has its own model of the game that it uses to keep track of what's happening, sending necessary data to the applets so they can display the current state.

Comment: Thanks alot. I get what you are saying now. Gonna remove all the drawing on the server side so only the logic is left.